# NP-hardness of CIRCUIT-SAT

Tags: computational-complexity

How to prove NP-hardness of CIRCUIT-SAT, without the use of other NP-complete problems but using Turing machines?

And, if it is possible, I need a full proof, not a sketch.

Comment: [These lecture notes](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~daw/teaching/cs170-s03/Notes/lecture22.pdf) might be useful

Comment: @Winther I have already read them. And they did not help.

Comment: Then I suggest you find yourself a good book on the subject or perhaps there is something free on the web (try searching for proofs of [Cook’s theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cook%E2%80%93Levin_theorem)). I doubt anyone will type up a proof for you here. Also a better place to ask questions of this kind is [Theoretical Computerscience SE](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/)